# Enforce Commited_AS to be no more than CommitLimit plus MemTotal on Linux

Tags: linux, memory

I'd like to limit amount of allocated memory to not exceed a certain limit because my system is heavily swapping. I'm fine with heuristic limit as long it's respected. I thought that `CommitLimit` is the [current limit](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting):

```
The current overcommit limit and amount committed are viewable in
/proc/meminfo as CommitLimit and Committed_AS respectively.
```

... but apparently not.

```
MemTotal:        2042712 kB
CommitLimit:     2064808 kB
SwapTotal:       1043452 kB

Committed_AS:    4751348 kB

vm.overcommit_memory = 0
```

As far as I understand, I enabled *heuristic* overcommit and the current limit should be equal *CommitLimit*. I don't understand why the keernel has commited almost 5GB of memeory. Is the total memory limit actually *SwapTotal* + *CommitLimit* + *MemTotal*?

This is on kernel 4.9.

Answer (score 2):

There is another [place in documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt#L931) that says strict overcommit mode (2) is neccessary for this use case.

Comment: TL;DR: `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`. That said, unless you're running hard realtime system without swap, I would consider that a poor configuration because lots of processes cannot really handle `malloc()` failing and will corrupt their memory structures when `malloc()` fails. In *best case*, such a process just crashes.